# How can I plot a smooth region based on data?

Tags: regions, geometry, visualization

Consider some region `region`, chosen for simplicity as a parallelepiped:

```
region= Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]
```

Let us generate points that belong to this region:

```
pt = RandomPoint[
   Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}], 
   10000];
Show[BoundaryMeshRegion[region, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
    2 -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Interpreter["Color"]["aqua"]]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True], 
 ListPointPlot3D[pt]]
```

[image]

Next, let us assume the following task: suppose we have points that belong to some unknown region. Let us use the same points set `pt` for simplicity. In principle, we may visualize the region by using `ListPointPlot3D`. However, there is a problem: if the number of points is large, then this command is very slow and slows the interface down. Also, continuous figures look much prettier.

Is it possible, using `pt`, to visualize the region without using ListPointPlot3D, but instead somehow continuously, such that the result would look like the `BoundaryMeshRegion` plot? E.g., to "interpolate" the set of boundary points from `pt` in order to obtain a smooth function, and then just plot it?

Comment: Perhaps `ConvexHullRegion` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are after [`BoundingRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html):

```
br = BoundingRegion[pt, "MinConvexPolyhedron"];

Graphics3D[{
  Directive[Opacity[0.1], RGBColor[{0, 1, 1}]],
  br,
  Black, Opacity[0.3], Point[pt]
}]
```

[image: 3D polyhedral region and points]

Above I am using your own definition of the list of points `pt`.

Answer (score 7):

Another way will be to use alpha shapes. This is available as [`ConcaveHullMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConcaveHullMesh.html) in MMA. Using your points `pt` we can get the following. I am setting the alpha parameter to `4` here.

```
Show[ConcaveHullMesh[pt, 4, Lighting -> {{"Directional", LightGreen, {{1., 0, 1.5}, {0, 0.5, 0}}}},BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3], LightYellow]],
 ListPointPlot3D[pt, PlotStyle -> Blue], Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

- Use `GradientFittedMesh`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pt = RandomPoint[
   Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}], 
   10000];
reg = GradientFittedMesh[pt, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  VertexNormals -> Automatic, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[0.5, Brown], {1, All} -> 
     Opacity[0.5, Green]}]
```

[image]

- 13.1 `ReconstructionMesh`.

```
ReconstructionMesh[pt,Method->{"AlphaShape","Alpha"->1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution using `ConvexHullMesh`:

```
chm = ConvexHullMesh[pt]
Length /@ {pt, MeshPrimitives[chm, 0]}
```

> {10000, 122}

```
Graphics3D[{
  Directive[Opacity[0.2]]
  , Blend[{Cyan, Gray}]
  , chm
  , region
  , Blue, AbsolutePointSize[2]
  , Point@pt
  }
 ]
```

[image]