# Seeking implementation of 3D alpha-shape

Tags: graphics3d, regions, polyhedra

The construction of the [*alpha-shape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape)
(a.k.a. alpha-complex) in 3D has
been implemented in [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html#fig__figgenregex), R, Matlab, Grasshopper, and likely other software systems.
I have not found an implementation in Mathematica. If anyone knows of an
implementation, that could save me some coding effort.

[image: Edelsbrunner]

---

Success! Thanks to Henrik Schumacher.

[image: alpha=0.2]

Comment: I think there  _is_ an implementation since MMA 13.0: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConcaveHullMesh.html I have not used it, yet. So I cannot tell how well it works.

Comment: To give credit where credit is due: I found this out by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269888/38178).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Oh, great! I wouldn't have guessed the name `ConcaveHull`. Thanks!

Comment: "Oh, great! I wouldn't have guessed the name `ConcaveHull`." Me neither! ^^

Comment: From the docs: "ConcaveHullMesh[{p1,p2,…},α] selects cells of dimension d where d is the embedding dimension of the points pi.". Yet in the output you posted I see a few isolated line segments. Did you call `ConcaveHullMesh` over multiple dimensions and merge them to get the above image? If not, I wonder why they show up.

Comment: @GregHurst: Yes, that's a merge of d=1 and d=2. Should also include d=1 but I think it doesn't matter for this alpha.